# How to specify which fields are serialised for authenticated and non-authenticated user in django rest framework?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Okay I know how to specify which fields (in serializer) are read_only or write only like this:

```
class CustomUserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('url', 'username','email','password')
        write_only_fields = ('password',)
```

and I know that permission class implemenets which http methods are allowed for authenticated or non-authenticated user request.

But what if I want that non-authenticated user can see only 'username', but authenticated/logged user can see also email? (for example)

Does anyone have an idea how to programm such behaviour in a modular way, so it could be applicable for multiple models/serializes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `GenericAPIView` or any of it's subclasses (which is pretty common), you can simply override the serializer's `__init__` to leave only selected fields:

```
class MySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MySerializer, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # GenericAPIView has an access to request object 
        request = self.context['request']
        if request.user.is_anonymous():
            field = self.fields['username']
            self.fields = {'username': field}
```

Of course, if you're calling serializer directly, you need to [pass the context yourself](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers#including-extra-context).

Comment: Thanks, this is able to detect whetehr the user is or is not authenticated, but Im not able to create fields parameter.

If I define it like this self.fields = ['username'] python raise attribute error "'list' object has no attribute 'items'"

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to have two different serializers, one for authenticated users and one for unathenticated users. You can then control which serializer is used by overriding [`get_serializer_class`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views#genericapiview) to return the correct serializer for the request.

You can access the current request with `self.request` within the method.

There is no easy, modular way to do this as it is surprisingly complex to make sure that incoming and outgoing data is still secure without using separate serializers.